# How to query MySQL for exact length and exact UTF-8 characters

Tags: mysql, utf-8

I have table with words dictionary in my language (latvian).

> `CREATE TABLE words (
>
>   value varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL
>
>   ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;`

And let's say it has 3 words inside:
`INSERT INTO words (value) VALUES ('tēja');

INSERT INTO words (value) VALUES ('vējš');

INSERT INTO words (value) VALUES ('feja');`

What I want to do is I want to find all words that is exactly 4 characters long and where second character is 'ē' and third character is 'j'

For me it feels that correct query would be:
`SELECT * FROM words WHERE value LIKE '_ēj_';`
But problem with this query is that it returs not 2 entries ('tēja','vējš') but all three.
As I understand it is because internally MySQL converts strings to some ASCII representation?

Then there is `BINARY` addition possible for `LIKE`
`SELECT * FROM words WHERE value LIKE BINARY '_ēj_';`
But this also does not return 2 entries ('tēja','vējš') but only one ('tēja'). I believe this has something to do with UTF-8 2 bytes for non ASCII chars?

So question:
**What MySQL query would return my exact two words ('tēja','vējš')?**

Thank you in advance

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29215763/1066234

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What MySQL query would return my exact two words ('tēja','vējš')?

```
SELECT * FROM words WHERE value LIKE '_ēj_' COLLATE utf8_bin;
```

The `utf8_bin` collation is not just diacritical-sensitive, but also case-sensitive. If you want to match only the letter-with-diacritical and you don't care about upper/lower case, you would have to [find](http://www.collation-charts.org/mysql60/) a `utf_..._ci` collation that doesn't treat `e` and `ē` as the same letter.

I can't immediately see one (there are plenty that don't collate `ē` at all, which would be okay if you only need case-sensitive matching on the non-diacritical letters). Interesting that the [Latvian collation](http://www.collation-charts.org/mysql60/mysql604.utf8_latvian_ci.html) treats macron-letters as the same as plain letters, which you don't want (it knows `š` is different from `s`).

Anyway, whatever collation you end up with, you will want to put your tables in that collation rather than manually specifying it in a query, so that comparisons can be properly indexed.

Comment: Thank you, I did exactly as you said - changed table to: CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin. I expect to use also some cyrilic symbols so I`ll stick to UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

You have to use proper collation.
Dunno for the latvian but here is the example for the german: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-collation-effect.html
to give you an idea

You can try some of the [baltic collations](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset-baltic-sets.html)