# matching exactly word in utf8 in where clause mysql

Tags: mysql, utf-8, matching

I have a query like this :

```
SELECT * FROM category_keyword  WHERE keyword = 'cho'
```

This query is return result `keyword ={ cho , chợ , chờ , chợ ...}`. I only want the result is keyword = 'cho' ( not 'chợ, chờ ...') . How can I do? 
The collation of table is `utf8_unicode_ci`

Comment: `SELECT * FROM category_keyword  WHERE CONVERT(keyword USING utf8) = 'cho'` Perhaps?

Comment: The result still include keyword = 'chợ '...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With utf8 collation, `cho` does equal `chờ`. If you want to compare as binary:

```
SELECT * FROM category_keyword WHERE keyword = CONVERT('cho' USING binary)
```

Comment: I searched forever for this kind of answer. Who gets the idea to use `USING binary` when the field is UTF8 and the search word/characters are UTF8...

Answer (score 1):

Change the collation for the column to utf8_bin.  This is better than using CONVERT because it allows the use of an index.  However, if you sometimes need utf8_bin (exact match) and sometimes need utf8_unicode_ci (for case folding and accent stripping), you are out of luck, performance-wise.

Comment: Yikes.  @Marcus Adams solution may be using the index.  But I don't know how!